# Add to Cart Woocommerce in Slider Revolution

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, revolution-slider

I managed to create an Add to cart button within a Slider Revolution copying the HTML from a standard add to cart button and pasting it in the text/HTML layer in SR.

```
<form class="cart" 
action="https://www.website.com/productname/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; line-height: 20px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 40px; padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 20px;">
<div class="quantity buttons_added" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; line-height: 0px; border-width: 0px; padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 100; font-size: 0px; margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px;">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5b6fd6bbcea2d" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; line-height: 0px; border-width: 0px; padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 100; font-size: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 5px;">Q</label>
<input type="number" id="quantity_5b6fd6bbcea2d" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" aria-labelledby="" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s;text-align: inherit;line-height: 2px;border-width: 0px 0px 3px;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;letter-spacing: 0px;font-weight: 100;font-size: 0px;min-width: 0px;display: none;"></div>
<button name="add-to-cart" value="2048" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt added" style="z-index: 14;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 2px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: rgb(153, 153, 153) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    visibility: inherit;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 12px 35px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    min-height: 0px;
    min-width: 0px;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Raleway;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(219,28,34,1.00);
    border-color: rgba(219,28,34,0);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;">BUY NOW!</button> <a href="https://www.website.com/cart/" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="View cart" style="display: none; transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; line-height: 20px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 1px 0px 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 100; font-size: 2px;">View cart</a>
</form>
```

I also change the quantity identifier for different sliders to avoid errors. This button will not display the quantity visually. I didn't use any functions to hide the quantity because I need it in the cart. I also didn't use the shortcode because I want to customize the button.

My question is: Is there a more elegant way of doing this. This solution also doesn't let me customize freely (please read within RevSlider) the button. What I'm doing in a very primitive way is to create a button outside RevSlider then copy the format to the HTML layer.
I've also tried: Creating an independent button that would then simulate the click on the default Add to Cart button but it didn't work as expected (no trigger).

Is someone familiar with trying to add a simple Add To Cart button within a Rev Slider?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested using the standard WooCommerce shortcode to generate the Add to Cart button?

```
[add_to_cart id="99"]
```

Change the ID to match your product ID you wish to add to the cart.

How to add a shortcode within a Rev Slider layer: https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/text-html-icons/

Comment: Thank You David. That was one initial solution. To clear better: Im not using a woocommerce product page, but a custom one. In this page when i use the button on the OP it triggers the cart and checkout modules in the same page. So the page is a one page checkout shopping.  Your solution creates a standart button inside RS but it never triggers the one page shopping. Also its harder to customize the shortcode without it changing woocommerce settings. Thanks - Edit- Im understanding that i require the complete form and not just a button.